# What will happen if var a = function b(){}

Tags: javascript

So I was reading about javascript functions in which I found out that there are two ways of writing a function first is

```
function b(){console.log("name")}
```

in which if I write b.name it gives b

and second way is to use

```
var a = function() {console.log("name")}
```

in which if I write a.name it gives a

so my question is what happens when we write a function like this

```
var a =function b(){console.log("name")}
```

in this case if I call `a();`
it will work fine 
and if I call `b();` it shows me an error
but if I write `a.name` it shows me b. Please can someone help me understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the function's **name** (type `a.name`) you'll receive `"b"`.

So apparently the identifier after the `function` keyword is the function's name, and the identifier before the assignment is the reference to the function.

If no assignment is specified, (i.e. your first example - `function b() {}` without the `var a =`), the name itself will be the reference (the object `b` will have the reference to the function).

Answer (score 3):

In

```
var a =function b(){console.log("name")}
```

...because you specified a name in the function expression, that becomes the function's name (e.g., `a.name` will return `"b"` [as will `b.name`*, of course, since `a` and `b` refer to the same function]). The name is only inferred (when possible) from the assignment expression when the function expression doesn't assign one.

(Note that inferring function names for functions created with anonymous function expressions is relatively new, a feature added in ES2015. Also note that the `name` property of functions wasn't officially added until then either.)

Here are all those demonstrated:

```js
function b1() {
  console.log("[inside] b1.name = " + b1.name);
}
console.log("b1.name = " + b1.name);
b1();

var a1 = function() {
  console.log("[inside] a1.name = " + a1.name);
};
console.log("a1.name = " + a1.name);
a1();

var a2 = function b2() {
  console.log("[inside] b2.name = " + b2.name);
};
console.log("a2.name = " + a2.name);
a2();
```

---

* If you use it where `b` is in scope. It isn't in scope outside the function, but it is *inside* the function. That's because when you use a named function expression (instead of a function declaration), the name of the function isn't added to the scope where the expression is defined (whereas with a function declaration, it is). But the name is still in scope *within* the function.

Comment: @YotamSalmon: That depends on where you write it. If you write it **within** the function, for instance, it will give you `"b"`. I'll clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (I was relating to the same way the OP tested the `a` and `b` expressions)

Comment: @YotamSalmon: Thank you for pointing it out, I might or might not have thought to clarify it otherwise. :-)